# Decoupling Capacitor voltage Selection

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, signal-integrity, high-speed, decoupling

In my board there are many IC's present and for all these IC's it's manufacturers specified the decoupling capacitors.

When I generated my initial BOM what I observed is 99% of these capacitors are of same value only voltage spec is different. Voltage varies from 6.3-50 V.

If I use 50 V rated capacitor for all decupling capacitors, I can optimize my BOM to some extent.

My question is is there any problem in using a decupling capacitor of 50 V for an IC which requires only 6.3 V decoupling capacitor specified by the manufacturer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl;dr: always check the specs and characteristics, and then you will know for sure.

Generally speaking, higher voltages, in the same package size, are better.  (Longer package sizes may incur extra ESL; thicker (taller) packages, slightly lower.)

The main things you need to know about ceramic capacitors, for AC purposes (like bypassing, filtering, etc.), are the C(V, temp), ESR and ESL.

ESR is typically inversely proportional to the amount of ceramic in the thing.  Much as it would be for a resistor made of some material.  The resistance arises from different means (dielectric loss and electrode sheet resistance rather than bulk resistivity), of course.  Easy enough, just look it up.

ESL is essentially determined by package dimensions.  So, body length is the most important factor, but width also matters; hence why wide-body types exist, for example.

C(temp) is as specified by the dielectric type.  Typically you don't choose anything worse than X5R, with X7R preferred -- at least, if you have any choice over it.  Type 2 dielectrics (such as these) have a wide and nonlinear temperature dependency, working best near room temperature, "freezing out" at low temps, and dropping off at high temps (approaching the Curie point).  Type 1 dielectrics are essentially proportional to temperature, as given by their tempco; C0G is the most common, and a very good dielectric in general, having low tempco (± 30 ppm), and extremely low ESR.

C(V) varies between dielectric type (and probably subtle chemical variations that aren't reflected by the temperature code alone) and construction, so there isn't much to infer about a given part from specs alone, other than simply that: if it's in a physically larger chip (larger chip size, taller height), it *can potentially have* a fuller C(V) curve; but it's not necessarily the case that the manufacturer will have fully utilized the internal volume of that chip, so this doesn't mean very much.  It does, however, mean that, if you require a large value at bias -- you will need at least some minimum size chip.

To be clear: the voltage rating is just that, a rating.  *It has no bearing on the actual electrical performance of the component.*

A recent comparison that came up on a forum was thus:

Specification: 0.1µF, ≥6.3V, 10%, B, 0402

1. [Murata GRM152B30J104KE19#](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=GRM152B30J104KE19%23) 6.3V, 0.2mm height
2. [Murata GRM152B31A104KE19#](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=GRM152B31A104KE19%23) 10V, 0.2mm
3. [Murata GRM155B11A104KA01#](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=GRM155B11A104KA01%23) 10V, 0.5mm
4. [Murata GRM155B31H104KE14#](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=GRM155B31H104KE14%23) 50V, 0.5mm

Comparing C(V) curves in pairs, 1 vs. 2 and 3 vs. 4:

[image: GRM152B30J104KE19# vs. GRM152B31A104KE19#]

[image: GRM155B11A104KA01# vs. GRM155B31H104KE14#]

The first two might well be physically identical parts (sold in different voltages just to fill the market niche); the curves match almost pixel for pixel.  It is curious that one is measured at 1V and the other, 0.5V -- higher AC voltage generally leads to higher capacitance readings (see the AC response plot on the link(s)), so this isn't quite a fair comparison.  Nonetheless, it seems they match well.

The second two show a clear discrepancy, with the higher-voltage part retaining a good, oh, five percentage points over its low-voltage sibling at 10V.

I didn't plot all four together, as we can clearly see the first pair (thin chips) are around -50% at 10V, while the second (thick chips) are -20%ish.  No surprise there -- the thick chips can hold more energy.

Again, this isn't necessarily a circumstance you can generalize from.  This is one case, between four carefully picked examples!  Keep in mind, engineering is a holistic study, including constraints like physical space, parts cost, assembly time/cost (BOM optimization), parts availability, etc.  To properly answer the given question: most likely it is fine, but ideally one goes through each device's requirements, and through the specs and characteristics of available capacitors, and chooses the set of fewest values that satisfy all requirements.  How much effort is worth spending on this, depends on the quantity in question.  If it's one-offs, or even a few hundred, consider the cost of your own time carefully; if it's tens of thousands, or millions even, cost-reducing a single part by fractions of a cent can well be worth some weeks of research!

Answer (score 2):

Higher voltage capacitors are generally bigger in at least one physical direction. So trying to get in close to a power pin on a fine pitch chip may be difficult with the higher voltage capactor.

A second concern might be price. however the increased quantity in the BOM may eliminate this concern.

Otherwise, the operation will be the same.

EDIT:

1. ESL: Inductance is the ability of current to establish a magnetic field. Electron flow in the metal terminals will create a magnetic field, and the displacement current between the plates can create a magnetic field. Higher voltage rating means more distance between the plates, so there is a longer current path so the inductance increases. But to maintain the capacitance value the area of the plates must increase (more layers in MLCC). So more parallel current paths reduce the inductance.
   Using the long edge of the ceramic chip for termination reduces the path length further reducing inductance.
   So voltage rating may influence ESL depending om construction.  The third contributor are the trace wires that connect the capacitor to the device. Larger capacitors often cannot get as close to the device as smaller ones requiring longer traces. This can often contribute more inductance than the ESL of the capacitor.
2. ESR: Internal resistance is primarily dielectric loss. There will be some resitance in the terminals. Ceramic capacitors have very low ESR values, so the voltage rating will have little effect.
3. Capacitance dependant on applied voltage.

Tim Williams has covered this in detail in his answer.

1. This dependance is due primarily to the rotation of electric dipoles. As the dipoles become aligned to the electric field, the permittivity decreases.
2. The voltage rating is based on the electric field reqiured to break down the lattice.

These two effects bear no relation to each other.

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_capacitor) has a good discussion on Ceramic Capacitors

Comment: Higher voltage caps have keep their value better under DC bias. And as they are bigger they have larger ESL. Not sure which is better for ESR.

Comment: Justme: "Higher voltage caps have keep their value better under DC bias": For ceramics, not really. Only as a consequence of greater dielectric volume. I will  add a note about ESL and ESR.

Comment: @RussellH,As you said please add  a note about ESL and ESR,will be helpful for us